# Prevent fields from being edited with echosign-api-php

Tags: php, echosign

I have a form that i use to fill out information and then use the echosign-api-php to send it. It sends fine and everything works perfect. What i am trying to figure out though, is the fields that get populated by the form for some reason are still editable when it gets to the echo sign server for the recipient to sign. Meaning he can change any text within those fields. Is there a way to prevent that?

Comment: No. anyone can use a web inspector and remove the disabled/readonly attribute of the input and place whatever they want into it.

Comment: Yeah but is it possible to just prepopulate certain fields with information and not really make them text boxes so that they can't be edited?

Comment: Anything is editable with a web inspector, validation needs to happen server side.

Comment: Yeah but I know its possible to prepopulate a form and just not make those fields editable only read only. Because when I signed up for internet in my area they sent a document from echosign and it had everything filled out except the signature filed and I couldn't edit anything

Comment: Did you open your web inspector, inspect the element, and remove the `readonly` attriubte from the input field?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can make field readonly, which won't allow the signer to edit the field's value.

If you are using text tags use something like this {{!name_es_:signer}}
'!' symbol is for readonly and when you will populate a value in it,signer will be able to see the value but not edit it.

For more information read this [text form tutorial](https://secure.echosign.com/doc/TextFormsTutorial.pdf)